# How do I sum the rows of two files with each other? (1 column of data in each) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

For example,

I have two files:

file1.log:

```
123
456
789
```

and

file2.log:

```
123
456
789
```

and I would like to sum them together quickly?

(My actual files have over a million lines each, but equal number of lines.)

The output would be:

```
246
912
1578
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
paste -d + file1.log file2.log | bc
```

Output:

```
246
912
1578
```

Answer (score 3):

awk to the rescue

```
awk '{getline t < "file2.log"; print $0+t}' file1.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print $1 + a[FNR]}' file1 file2
246
912
1578
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `paste` and `bc` are the best solution here. Just for fun here is one way to do it with pure bash (adapted from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26605/17666) on unix.sx):

```
while read n1 <&3 && read n2 <&4; do
  echo $((n1 + n2))
done 3<file1.log 4<file2.log
```

Or use the `-u fd` option with `read` (thanks *rici*):

```
while read -u3 n1 && read -u4 n2; do
  echo $((n1 + n2))
done 3<file1.log 4<file2.log
```

Output:

```
246
912
1578
```

Comment: @rici: I have added it as an alternative. To me the new version looks slightly clearer, but neither solution is pretty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could be another option

```
paste file1.log file2.log | awk '{print $1 + $2;}'

#246
#912
#1578
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution:

`perl -lne 'BEGIN{open $in1,shift; open $in2,shift} while($n1=<$in1> and $n2=<$in2>){print $n1+$n2}' file1.log file2.log`

A more readable (but slightly slower) version:

```
open my $in1, "<", shift;
open my $in2, "<", shift;
while ( my $n1 = <$in1> and my $n2 = <$in2> ) {
    print $n1 + $n2
    print "\n";
}
close($in1);
close($in2);
```

Just for kicks, I benchmarked the above vs all other solutions listed here.
They all produce the same output.
The input files are lists of integers from 1 to 999999
`seq 999999 > file1.log ; seq 999999 > file2.log`

Benchmark results (10 runs each):

```
shell@thor                     0.070/s
paste@cyrus                    0.410/s
awk@anubhava                   0.546/s
perl_5.6.1                     1.06/s
paste@veerendra                1.32/s
perl_5.20 (readable version)   1.37/s
awk@karakfa (awk 3.1.5)        1.44/s
perl_5.20                      1.75/s
```